# Browserify require inside object

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

First question here and it is 3:30AM so please bear with me as I try to explain my question.

I'm in the situation that I need a very big javascript object. Good practice learns me that I shouldn't expose anything to the window object unless absolutely necessary.

This object I made requires some sort of customization (settings) and an object containing different kind of customization (levels). The first object is not that big, but the second one is becoming quite big and will grow bigger in the future.

I figured it would be nice to split these objects into different files and want to use browserify for it. I dont however want the two objects available within the window scope.

```js
// settings.js
var settings = {
  "setting1": "hellp",
  "setting2": "world"
}
module.exports = settings;

//levels.js
var levels = {
  "level1": {
    name: "level1",
    type: "flat",
  },
  "level2": {
    name: "level2",
    type: "hills"
  } //about 10 more...
}
module.exports = levels;

//world.js
var world = function() {
    var self = this;
    var settings = require('settings.js');
    var levels = require('levels.js');

    self.test = function() {
      console.log(settings['setting1'] + " " + settings['setting2']; console.log(levels['level1'].name);
      }
      return self;
    }
```

I work with browserify and gulp to append this into one /dist/world.js but in a test html page it always shows "world is undefined", while it does work when I append the file myself.

I figured I did something wrong with browserify but the gulp task I use for it works on other projects:

```js
function handleError(level, error) {
    gutil.log(error.message);
    process.exit(1);
}

// Convenience handler for error-level errors.
function onError(error) {
    handleError.call(this, 'error', error);
}

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    var b = browserify({
        entries: './main.js',
        paths: ['./www-src'],
        debug: true
    });

    return b.transform(p)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', onError)
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

basically what im calling is this in the index.html:

```js
//index.html
var world = new world();
world.test()
```

and it throws the "world is undefined" error

Is anyone able to give me any pointers how to fix this issue? Would really appreciate any help!

---

update:
I know that IFFE means immediately invoked function expression, in other words a function that gets executed immediately. What I dont get is how to access this.

Comment: Browserify wraps your code in an IIFE. Where are you using `new world`?

Comment: @elclanrs could you give me any help with the issue?